# Method to measure P-Scalability in Distributed Systems

Tags: scalability, distributed-computing, distributed-system

P-Scalbility measure is method to measure the scalability of distributed systems. I have tried hard to find its formula in google. But could not find it clearly on any place.

If any one know can please explain or provide the formula details or resources from where i can understand this formula.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, did you find an answer in the mean-time?

If not here is what I found so far:

I found a formula and a brief explanation of the p-scalability in the paper [Evaluating the Scalability of Distributed Systems](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=862209) of [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.96.5181&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

[image: Part of *Evaluating the scalability of Distributed Systems* concerning the P-Scalability]

The reference 11 is:

> P.P. Jogalekar and C.M. Woodside, aA Scalability Metric for
>   Distributed Computing Applications in Telecommunications,o
>   Proc. *15th Int'l Teletraffic Congress Teletraffic --- Contributions to the
>   Information Age*, pp. 101-110, 1997.

For which I did not manage to find a free available version online. But is is written by the same authors of **Evaluating the scalability of Distributed Systems**. With an university account you could retrieve a copy.

If I find further details, I will edit the answer.

I reference also [a related question asked by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278855/how-to-measure-scalability-in-a-distributed-system)

Comment: Although it is very late answer. But it was right one.. I found it later on. Anyways. Thanks