# How to measure scalability in a distributed system

Tags: scalability, units-of-measurement, measurement

Are there in the literature some standard **scalability measures for distributed systems**? I'm searching in google (and also google scholar) but I came up with only few papers (e.g., https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=862209).
In particular, I was wondering if there are some scalability measures for the three axes of the AKF cube or cube of the scalability (http://microservices.io/articles/scalecube.html), which is described in the book The Art of Scalability, by Abbott and Fischer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such unit for scalability. However, it is often illustrated by chart having the amount of resources in X-axis and throughput or latency in the Y-axis.